# Why does java.awt.Button ask for boolean value?

Tags: java, button

1. I get the error message "The constructor Button(String, int, Font, Font, Color, Color) is undefined" in the options[0], [1], and [2] lines, and am quite stuck at the moment!
2. In the for-loop I get the message "The method setSelected(boolean) is undefined for the type Button".

How do you create a simple button with the "import java.awt.Button;" library?

**Menu Class**

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import me.nielsen.firestorm.utils.Fonts;

public class Menu {

    private final Button[] options;
    private int currentSelection;
    private final Font font1 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 32);
    private final Font font2 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48);

    public Menu() {
        options = new Button[3];
        options[0] = new Button("Play", 200 + 0 * 80, font1, font2, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW);
        options[1] = new Button("Options", 200 + 1 * 80, font1, font2, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW);
        options[2] = new Button("Exit", 200 + 2 * 80, font1, font2, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW);
        // new Button(text, textY, font, selectedFont, color, selectedColor, selected)
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Firestorm.WIDTH, Firestorm.HEIGHT);
        Fonts.drawString(g, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 72), Color.ORANGE, Firestorm.TITLE, 80);

        for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
            if(i == currentSelection)
                options[i].setSelected(true);
            else options[i].setSelected(false);

        options[i].render(g);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [no public constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#Button()) taking as much as parameter as the one you are trying to invoke. As for `setSelected`, it simply does not exists on the Button class (hence the **compiler error message**).

You can create Button like this:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
Button button2 = new Button("Foobar");
```

For `setSelected`, you are probably looking at the wrong component: a button is not explicitly selected as are radio button or check boxes. You might want to look at `Checkbox`, `JRadioButton` or `JCheckBox` (beware that the `J` classes are Swing not AWT) and you might want to read this [Oracle tutorial on AWT and Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/awt/index.html).

Comment: Also, you should probably use Swng (or FX)rather than AWT for GUI components. Using AWT has been obsolete for at least 20 years.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much the first code I'm doing in java and I'm just following a YouTube course, but its a few years old and things have changed apparently.

Comment: I concur with FredK, learn JavaFX, SWT or Swing rather than AWT. Oracle provide tutorial for that.